# SQL command line not opening after installing Oracle 11g express edition

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I've installed Oracle 11g express edition on my windows 10 machine, after that I've tried to open "Run sql command line", but it didn't launch. I checked the services, all services are running. I was unable to diagnose the problem. Help me with this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5972538/62576

Comment: Did you try to run command prompt (that oldfashioned black window with white letters), get the `C:\>` prompt and a blinking cursor, type `sqlplus hr/hr`, press ENTER key and see what happens? I would, but I don't have Windows 10 so ... I'm just guessing - maybe it'll help.